# Delete duplicate elements in String in R

Tags: r, string

I've got some problems deleting duplicate elements in a string. 
My data look similar to this:

---

```
idvisit     path
1           1,16,23,59
2           2,14,14,19
3           5,19,23,19
4           10,10
5           23,23,27,29,23
```

---

I have a column containing an unique ID and a column containing a path for web page navigation. 
The right column contains some cases, where pages just were reloaded and the page were tracked twice or even more. 
The pages are separated with commas and are saved as factors. 
My problem is, that I don't want to have multiple pages in a row, so the data should look like this.

---

```
idvisit     path
1           1,16,23,59
2           2,14,19
3           5,19,23,19
4           10
5           23,27,29,23
```

---

The multiple pages next to each other should be removed. I know how to delete a specific multiple number using regexpressions, but I have about 20.000 different pages and can't do this for all of them. 
Does anyone have a solution or a hint, for my problem?

Thanks 
Sebastian

Answer (score 5):

We can use `tidyverse`.  Use the `separate_rows` to split the 'path' variable by the delimiter (`,`) to convert to a long format, then grouped by 'idvisit', we `paste` the run-length-encoding `values`

```
library(tidyverse)
separate_rows(df1, path) %>%
       group_by(idvisit) %>%
       summarise(path = paste(rle(path)$values, collapse=","))
# A tibble: 5 × 2
#  idvisit        path
#    <int>       <chr>
#1       1  1,16,23,59
#2       2     2,14,19
#3       3  5,19,23,19
#4       4          10
#5       5 23,27,29,23
```

---

Or a `base R` option is

```
df1$path <- sapply(strsplit(df1$path, ","), function(x) paste(rle(x)$values, collapse=","))
```

NOTE: If the 'path' column is `factor` class, convert to `character` before passing as argument to `strsplit` i.e. `strsplit(as.character(df1$path), ",")`

Comment: I was trying verify your R-base solution, for 3rd row: `x <- "5,19,23,19"`, `x <- strsplit(x, ",")`, then: `paste(rle(x)$values, collapse = ",")`, I get: `[1] "c(\"5\", \"19\", \"23\", \"19\")"`

Comment: For using `rle` function, under this context, first you need to sort the the values, I don't know if that is relevant or not for @SebastianEttner problem. For example: `x <- c(2,2,1,2,3,2,1,3,3,2,1)`, then: `rle(x)$value`
will be: `[1] 2 1 2 3 2 1 3 2 1`, but with: `rle(x[order(x)])` we get: `rle(x[order(x)])$value` we get: `[1] 1 2 3`

Comment: @DavidLeal The whole idea here is to *not* sort the values. The desired output suggests that only the *consecutive* dupes should be removed. Otherwise he could just use `unique`. The reason for the output you are getting is because you haven't explored the output of `strsplit(x, ",")` first.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I repeated the steps, using now: `x <- strsplit(x, ",")[[1]]` and now I get: `[1] "5,19,23,19"` the repeated value (19) is still there.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, It confused me the phrase from the question: "My problem is, that i don´t want to have multipe pages in a row", Now I understand it applies only for consecutive values, then rows: 2, 4, then this second proposal works.

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr` package, with function: `str_replace_all`, I think it gets what you want using the following regular expression: `([0-9]+),\\1`and then replace it with `\\1` (we need to scape the `\` special character):

```
library(stringr)
> str_replace_all("5,19,23,19", "([0-9]+),\\1", "\\1")
[1] "5,19,23,19"
> str_replace_all("10,10", "([0-9]+),\\1", "\\1")
[1] "10"
> str_replace_all("2,14,14,19", "([0-9]+),\\1", "\\1")
[1] "2,14,19"
```

You can use it in a array form: `x <- c("5,19,23,19", "10,10", "2,14,14,19")` then:

```
str_replace_all(x, "([0-9]+),\\1", "\\1")
[1] "5,19,23,19" "10"         "2,14,19"
```

or using `sapply`:

```
result <- sapply(x, function(x) str_replace_all(x, "([0-9]+),\\1", "\\1"))
```

Then:

```
> result
  5,19,23,19        10,10   2,14,14,19 
"5,19,23,19"         "10"    "2,14,19"
```

**Notes**:

The first line is the attribute information:

```
> str(result)
Named chr [1:3] "5,19,23,19" "10" "2,14,19"
- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "5,19,23,19" "10,10" "2,14,14,19"
```

If you don't want to see them (it does not affect the result), just do:

```
attributes(result) <- NULL
```

Then,

```
> result
[1] "5,19,23,19" "10"         "2,14,19"
```

Explanation about the regular expression used: `([0-9]+),\\1`

1. `([0-9]+)`: Starts with a group 1 delimited by `()` and finds any digit (at least one)
2. `,`: Then comes a punctuation sign: `,` (we can include spaces here, but the original example only uses this character as delimiter)
3. `\\1`: Then comes an identical string to the group 1, i.e.: the repeated number. If that doesn't happen, then the pattern doesn't match.

Then if the pattern matches, it replaces it, with the value of the variable `\\1`, i.e. the first time the number appears in the pattern matched.

*How to handle more than one duplicated number, for example `2,14,14,14,19`?:*

Just use this regular expression instead: `([0-9]+)(,\\1)+`, then it matches when at least there is one repetition of the delimiter (right) and the number. You can try other possibilities using this [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/JUS9Y5/2) (in MHO it more user friendly than other online regular expression checkers).

I hope this would work for you, it is a flexible solution, you just need to adapt it with the pattern you need.

Comment: Nice idea. Though the `supply` addition is not needed. No reason to run a vectorized operation in a loop- a very bad practice in R. Though this will fail for repetitions >2, e.g. for: `"5,19,19,19,20"`.